# Resetting a Sequelize database

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

### The Situation

I am writing integration tests for a Node.JS project that uses Sequelize + Postgres.  I would like to ensure that the test database is completely reset before tests are run.

### Additional Information

1. I would prefer a solution that is done via CLI + sequelize.
2. I do not care about the content of the test database.
3. I do not want my test user to need any privileges outside of the test database.

I have a `pretest` script that runs:

```sh
NODE_ENV=test yarn migrate
```

### The Exploration

I believe `db:drop` and `db:create` do not work in postgres.

In Rails I might use `db:migrate:reset`

I know Sequelize has `db:migrate:undo:all` but I believe that rolls back each migration individually, which feels like a waste of time if my intent is simply to drop all tables.

### The Question

How do I most effectively accomplish the goal of running migrations on the test database from a clean slate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [Sequelize Command-Line Interface (CLI)](https://github.com/sequelize/cli), then you can use `db:create` and `db:drop` no matter what RDBMS you are using.

Here is usage, I test it using `postgres:9.6`:

```sh
☁  node-sequelize-examples [master] npx sequelize-cli db:drop

Sequelize CLI [Node: 10.16.2, CLI: 5.5.1, ORM: 5.21.3]

Loaded configuration file "src/config/config.js".
Using environment "development".
Executing (default): DROP DATABASE "node-sequelize-examples"
Database node-sequelize-examples dropped.
☁  node-sequelize-examples [master] npx sequelize-cli db:create

Sequelize CLI [Node: 10.16.2, CLI: 5.5.1, ORM: 5.21.3]

Loaded configuration file "src/config/config.js".
Using environment "development".
Executing (default): CREATE DATABASE "node-sequelize-examples"
Database node-sequelize-examples created.
```

`src/config/config.js`:

```sh
module.exports = {
  development: {
    username: process.env.POSTGRES_USER,
    password: process.env.POSTGRES_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.POSTGRES_DB,
    host: process.env.POSTGRES_HOST,
    port: process.env.POSTGRES_PORT,
    dialect: 'postgres',
    logging: console.log,
  },
  test: {
    username: process.env.POSTGRES_USER,
    password: process.env.POSTGRES_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.POSTGRES_DB,
    host: process.env.POSTGRES_HOST,
    port: process.env.POSTGRES_PORT,
    dialect: 'postgres',
  },
  production: {
    username: process.env.POSTGRES_USER,
    password: process.env.POSTGRES_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.POSTGRES_DB,
    host: process.env.POSTGRES_HOST,
    port: process.env.POSTGRES_PORT,
    dialect: 'postgres',
  },
};
```

Check the database using `psql`:

```sh
# psql -U testuser node-sequelize-examples
psql (9.6.11)
Type "help" for help.

node-sequelize-examples=# \d
No relations found.
```

Comment: Great suggestion; unfortunately it looks like postgresql doesn't support those (`ERROR: Dialect postgresql does not support db:create / db:drop commands`)

Comment: `db:create` and `db:drop` support has now been added for PostgreSQL.

Comment: `mariadb` doesn't have one. This solution is not ideal.

Answer (score 2):

try this solution:

using jest hook pretest and multiples steps together

```
"pretest": "NODE_ENV=test sequelize db:migrate:undo:all && NODE_ENV=test sequelize db:drop && NODE_ENV=test sequelize db:create && NODE_ENV=test sequelize db:migrate,
"test": "NODE_ENV=test jest"
```

Comment: Please add an explanation for your answer